# How to handle frontend/ backend session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

So , the codeigniter use a table to store session. The problem is , if someone has login to the backend , then he will also be detected as logined in the frontend, as there is only one application of codeigniter, the check session is shared between frontend and backend, how can I separate it? Thanks

Here is how I check the session:

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
}
```

Here is the session setting in the config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I have not create two application but only use sub-dir method

e.g.

```
controller
-admin
-admin_product.php
-front
-front_product.php

views is the similiar
```

Thanks

Comment: Use different session keys for frontend/backend instead of `is_logged_in` for everything. Make sense? If not can you explain the problem a little better?

Comment: You'll will have to initialize session manually, once for front-end & once for back-end (each time setting different "sess_cookie_name" so both are separate.